# UIAlertView shows up twice

Tags: iphone, uialertview

My alertview appears twice and requires 2 user clicks to dismiss.

```
    - (void) showAlert: (NSString *) message
{
 UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You chose"
             message: message
            delegate: self
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
            otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
 av.tag = SLIDER_ALERT;
 [av show];

}
```

I am then releasing the alertview in the delegate method "alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex: (int) index"

I suspect the problem is that I have built my own view hierarchy programmaticaly. I have one parent view for the viewcontroller. Under that i have 2 other views (parentView -> subview1 and subview2). I've tried to call [self.view addSubview: av] but that does not work. Neither does bringToFrontSubView:

Any help would be much appreciated

Peyman

Comment: FYI, this code is leaks memory, even though you say you are releasing it later. But you are not, because `av` goes out of scope as soon as that method returns.

Comment: thanks Daniel. I've added an autorelease to it.

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you sure that the showAlert function is not called twice?

Comment: The proper way to show an UIAlertView ist to call [av show]; and right after this [av release];. The system will release it after it is dismissed by the user (by tapping one of the buttons). Besides this the code is right. This means showAlert: is called twice in your app. Just search the project for showAlert: and have a look at your code.

Comment: I get the same issue, I have a debugAlert function which takes a message as a parameter. If I call it twice consecutively, the second alert appears twice, totaling 3 times. It is a very weird issue, may be related to the underlying issue you are having. Will post when/if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Alert code is fine (other than the release, mentioned in the comments).

[av show] is all that's required to show a view. You don't add UIAlertViews as subviews.

Comment: I've narrowed the problem to the interaction between the slider and the UIAlertview. The UISlider is calling its  alertView: clickedButtonAtIndex: delegate twice. I have set the UISlider.continous property to NO so theoretically the slider should return only 1 (end value) on slider release. But its not. Its calling the delegate x2. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With using autorelease the Alert View seems to be twice or 3 times. And for iOS4 it needs to be autoreleased otherwise it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Call it after a delay of 0.1 sec [self performSelector:@selector(showAlert:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.10];

Hope this will solve your problem.